# Laplacian in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, laplacian

I want expression for Laplacian in orthogonal curvilinear coordinates ($u,v$). I can obtain the expression by two methods and they seem to give different results. Can anybody point out the mistake?

\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(u_x p_u + v_x p_v\right) \\
 &=& u_{xx}p_u + u_xp_{ux} + v_{xx}p_v + v_xp_{vx} \\
 &=& u_{xx}p_u + u_x\partial_{u}(u_x p_u + v_x p_v) + v_{xx}p_v + v_x \partial_{v}(u_x p_u + v_x p_v) \\
 &=&  u_{xx}p_u + u^2_xp_{uu}+ u_xv_xp_{uv} + v_{xx}p_v + v^2_xp_{vv} +  u_xv_xp_{uv}\\
 &=& u_{xx}p_u + u^2_xp_{uu} + v_{xx}p_v + v^2_xp_{vv} + 2  u_xv_xp_{uv} \\
\end{eqnarray}

similarly,
\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} &=& u_{yy}p_r + u^2_yp_{uu} + v_{yy}p_s + v^2_yp_{vv} + 2  u_yv_yp_{uv}
\end{eqnarray}

So that,
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y^2}  &=& (u_{xx} + u_{yy} )p_u + (u^2_y + u^2_x)p_{uu} + (v_{xx}+v_{yy})p_v + (v^2_x+v^2_y)p_{vv} + 2  (r_ys_y + r_xs_x)u_{uv} \\
\nabla ^2  p &=& (u_{xx} + u_{yy} )p_u + (u^2_y + u^2_x)p_{uu} + (v_{xx}+v_{yy})p_v + (v^2_x+v^2_y)p_{vv} \\
\nabla ^2  p &=& (\Delta u)p_u + (|\nabla u|)^2 p_{uu} + (\Delta v)p_v + (|\nabla v|)^2 p_{vv}  \quad{Eq:first}
\end{eqnarray}

Expression for Laplacian can also be obtained  [via](https://www.jfoadi.me.uk/documents/lecture_mathphys2_05.pdf),
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla = \left(\frac{1}{h_u}\frac{\partial }{\partial u},\frac{1}{h_v}\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

where, \begin{eqnarray}
h_u = \left|\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}\right| \quad \quad h_v = \left|\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}\right|
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla ^2  p &=& \frac{1}{h_u h_v}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\left[\frac{h_v}{h_u}\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}\right] + \frac{\partial }{\partial v}\left[\frac{h_u}{h_v}\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right]\right) \quad{Eq:second}
\end{eqnarray}

When I want to compare the two results Eq.({Eq:first}) and Eq.({Eq:second}), coefficients of the term $p_{uu}$ are different.

\begin{eqnarray}
|\nabla u|^2 &=&\left|\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 \right| \\
\frac{1}{h^2_u} &=& \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)^2}
\end{eqnarray}

These coefficients are clearly different. Can one show that exp(1) and exp(2) are the same? If yes, what mistake am I making?

Comment: Could you explain how you are getting the $\frac{h_v}{h_u}$ term in the second equation? $v$ is surely a constant with respect to $u$ but I'm not sure about $h_v$ meaning that you can't simply put it inside of your derivative.